# missing values in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have table `EMP` which has only 1 column `id`

I have below input

```
1
3
4
6
10
```

I want output

```
2
5
7
8
9
```

I have written the below query

```
select level from dual connect by level<=10 
minus 
select id from emp;
```

Is there any other way to write this query? Can this be written without using `connect by`

Comment: Do you already have the sequence 1 to 10 in some table?

Comment: There are other ways, but what would make any other way preferrable to what you are doing now? Why are you looking for something else, and how will you decide what is best?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole I gave interview in dustche bank and they told me to do without using connect by. unfortunately I was rejected , because I couldn't do the same.

Answer (score 1):

`Is there any other way to write this query. Can this be written without using connect by`

Yes it can be written without `connect by`. The same thing can be done with CTE(it requires you some typing to do, but it's more generic in terms of code portability), which in this case does the same thing - generates a sequence of numbers. The idea is pretty much the same, different wording.

```
-- CTE. generates numbers from 1 to 10
with numbers(digit) as(
  select 1 from dual
  union all
  select digit + 1
    from numbers
   where digit < 10
)
select digit from numbers
minus 
select id from emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky one:

```
select rownum as id
from ALL_OBJECTS --(OR OTHER BIG TABLE)
where rownum <= 5    
minus
select id from emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can take the results in a different form, then you can write this using `lead()`:

```
select (id + 1) as first_missing_id,
       (next_id - 1) as last_missing_id,
       (next_id - id - 1) as num_missing
from (select e.*, lead(e.id) over (order by e.id) as next_id
      from emp e
     ) e
where next_id <> id + 1;
```

This shows the missing ranges of ids.  It is also probably faster than any version that creates a separate row for each id.

Answer (score 0):

Public system varray `sys.odcinumberlist`:

```
select column_value
from   table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
minus
select id from emp
```